# Checking on Android OS for unauthorized access and the last connection of the charging cable to the phone

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb

The question arises, how can I view the last attempt to connect the charger to the phone and also track the last attempt to select passwords and attempts of unauthorized access and authorization on Android 5.0 and older? If yes, how can I implement the receipt of this information in the form of an application.

Comment: Check Settings -> Battery if I remember correctly there should a battery graph on which you can identify the last charging.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. While running commands/scripts from end-users PoV is still on-topic, please note that *app development is off-topic* since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (*but not necessarily developers*) solving their issues. It seems you have posted [the same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72113649/2821954) which should be more suitable for app development issues (despite the quality issue as of currently written).

Answer (score 0):

I agree too @Robert 's comment. However, [AccuBattery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.accubattery&hl=en_IN&gl=US) does exactly what you want; show timestamps of all charging and discharging activities; it works from Android 5 all the way up to Android 13 Developer Preview (older than 5, I dont really think if there's any)